# How to set markdown snippet trigger automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to the official document, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown

> **Snippets for Markdown**
>
> There are several built-in Markdown snippets included in VS Code -
>   press Ctrl+Space (Trigger Suggest) and you get a context specific list
>   of suggestions.

Does there any way, trigger snippet automatically when I type word, because it's troublesome, press Ctrl+Space

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to override `Trigger Suggest` with your own keybinding?

Comment: This is final alternative,because I'm used to keep default short cut. If there is no auto trigger option, I will do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"[markdown]": {
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
  },
},
```

This enables IntelliSense automatically when you start typing. By default, this will show snippets and word based suggestions (suggestions based on words in the current document). To disable word based suggestions, set:

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
}
```

You can also set:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```

If you always want snippets to show before word base suggestions

Comment: Additionally I've found that installing and enabling the `yzhang.markdown-all-in-one` also enables search of some snippet prefixes (e.g. `//1`, `//2`) that would otherwise not appear.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inconsistency in VS Code and it is a known issue. Markdown snippets do not get auto-completion. Probably it will be fixed in next release.

> Yes this is an inconsistency. Full extensions get auto (7x24) completion by default (e.g. latex, cake), some built-in extensions like Markdown do not.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1617#issuecomment-166999086

Comment: This is the designed behavior, not an issue