# Create snippet README.md file for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, readme

I'm trying to create a snippet for files **md** using command **"New global snippets file"**.
They create new file **md.code-snnippets**, but they didn't work. If I put code inside **javascript.json** file they work in js file.

````js
{
"Readme code poster": {
            "prefix": "cjs",
            "description": "JavaScript code inside instruction",
            "body": "```js \n \"$1\" \n```"
}
````

I also try rename file to **md.json** it didn't help.

Expected result inside .md file:

````js
> ```js
> 
> 
> ```
````

Comment: every line in a snippet is a separate string in the `body` array

Comment: Works fine for me.  It would help if you showed what you wanted the snippet to actually produce - a sample of the final product - it looks very strange but does work.  If you want it to work in markdown files only you should tell us that. 
 @rioV8: If the body is only a single entry it doesn't have to be in an array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639841/how-to-set-markdown-snippet-trigger-automatically for a fix, `markdown` files are a little different than most other files in snippet completion.