# Can we write code snippet for markdown language in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, markdown, code-snippets

Why markdown language not seems to be supported by code-snippets in vs-code? I've also tried writing `"scope: "md"` but it also doesn't work.

```json
{
    "Print to console": {
        "scope": "markdown",
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "description"
    }
}
```

Comment: in which file did you put this snippet?

Comment: There is a simple fix for markdown snippets not suggesting on type only, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639841/how-to-set-markdown-snippet-trigger-automatically/45910856#45910856 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88129#issuecomment-573962949 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28048#issuecomment-306616235.  This is a duplicate really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some of the other snippet files like `html.json`.

Save this file with **File** | **Save As...** as `markdown.json` in the same directory.

Fill in your snippet.

In the Markdown file type your snippet prefix and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and select the snippet you want.

It seems there is not a completion provider that shows the possible completions while you type or it is not enabled by default.

Comment: Actually completion provider is enabled because snippets for all other language is working correctly but not this one.

Comment: This works for me. I was actually creating the global snippet and writing the `scope: markdown` but it seems that rather than select global snippet i have to select markdown language snippets option.

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi A completion provider is bound to a language on construction

Comment: So why does adding global snippets works for python, cpp, java and all other languages but not for markdown?

Comment: @ShantanuTripathi Maybe if you define snippets in the package.json of an extension you get an implicit completion provider for that language